# Changing Code to Recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Can anyone help me convert this code to make it run recursively?
I'm not exactly sure how.
The goal of the code is to count the amount of numbers in an array are divisible by k.

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,9}
int k = 3;
int count;
for (int i = 0;i <a.length; i ++){
    if (a[i] % 3 == 0){
        count ++;
    }
}

return count;
```

Comment: For reference, this is not a good fit for recursion.  At least not in Java.  A recursive solution wouldn't be any simpler or less error-prone than an iterative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to find what's changing with each loop iteration, and passing that into the recursive method:

```
int count(int[] array, int k, int i){
    if(i>=array.length)
        return 0;
    boolean divisible = array[i] % k == 0;
    return count(array, k, i+1) + (divisible?1:0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering what that ? mark in the return statement meant.
Also, just checking, the Big O for this is O(n) right? It depends on the size of the array.

Comment: Showing that it's O(n) is easy if you show that it is called exactly `n` times by setting and using a loop invariant.  `a?b:c` is shorthand for `if a {b;} else {c;}`

Answer (score 1):

No need to use recursion.  You can simply check whether each member of the list is divisible by 3.  Then count the number of `True`s. In Mathematica this is straightforward.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9};
Count[Divisible[#, 3] & /@ a, True]
```

This returns: 3